# How do I get the background color to update on pills with Bootstrap Scrollspy?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, scrollspy

I am trying to use the Bootstrap Scrollspy within a collapsible panel. Everything seems to be working except the pills don't update/change color when I clicked on them. I think I have to change the CSS but I am not sure what I need to change.

HTML

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
      Title 1
    </a>
  </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <nav class="col-sm-3" id="myScrollspy">
                            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                                <li class="active"><a href="#Subtitle1">Subtitle1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#Subtitle2">Subtitle2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#Subtitle3">Subtitle3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#Subtitle4">Subtitle4</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#Subtitle5">Subtitle5</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#Subtitle6">Subtitle6</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#Subtitle7">Subtitle7</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <div id="Subtitle1">
                                <h1>Subtitle1</h1>
                                <p>some text</p>
                            </div>
                            <div id="Subtitle2">
                                <h1>Subtitle2</h1>
                                <p>some text</p>
                            </div>
                            <div id="Subtitle3">
                                <h1>Subtitle3</h1>
                                <p>some text</p>
                            </div>
                            <div id="Subtitle4">
                                <h1>Subtitle4</h1>
                                <p>some text</p>
                            </div>
                            <div id="Subtitle5">
                                <h1>Subtitle5</h1>
                                <p>some text</p>
                            </div>
                            <div id="Subtitle6">
                                <h1>Subtitle6</h1>
                                <p>some text</p>
                            </div>
                            <div id="Subtitle7">
                                <h1>Subtitle7</h1>
                                <p>some text</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
      Title 2
    </a>
   </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
    <a data-toggle = "collapse" data-parent = "#accordion" href = "#collapseThree">
      Title 3
    </a>
  </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /container -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

CSS

```
  body {
  position: relative;
  }

ul.nav-pills {
      top: 50px;
      position: fixed;
  }

  div.col-sm-9 div {
      height: 250px;
      font-size: 28px;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add some custom bootstrap attributes on the first body tag. This will make the pills buttons to highlight, although you will soon see that you will run into another little problem. The highlighted state will skip the two last buttons, from 4 to 7, since the scrolling bar will reach the bottom of the browser too fast. This is going to be a bit tricky to do I guess. Also it will depends on the length of each section's text

HTML:

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#myScrollspy">
```

Comment: Thanks. I see what you mean. It is now jumping on the last buttons. Is there any kind of a work around for this?

Answer (score 0):

I used the custom bootstrap attributes that where recommended.

HTML

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#myScrollspy">
```

I then changed the height of each section in the CSS to fix the jumping issue.

CSS

```
  #Subtitle1,
  #Subtitle2,
  #Subtitle3,
  #Subtitle4,
  #Subtitle5,
  #Subtitle6,
  #Subtitle7 {
      height: 500px;
  }
```